# powershell result redirect into file

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

```
$z = "slc10nzf" , "slc12vbi"

$cls = gc C:\temp\cls.txt

foreach ($cl in $cls)
{
    $vms = Get-Vm -ComputerName (Get-ClusterNode -Cluster $cl)

    foreach ($vm in $vms)
    {
        $name = $vm.Name

        if ($z -eq $name)
        {
            Write-Output "$name, $cl" | Out-File c:\temp\result.txt -Append
        }
     }
}
```

we have 4 hyper-v cluster and VM's are running on it 
cluster names:

> slchypervcl001,slchypervcl002,slchypervcl003,slchycl001

I have created script that to find which VM belongs to which cluster.
the script is working fine but the script redirecting result with duplicate any help appreciate.

the present script output is:

```
slc10nzf, slchypervcl001
slc12vbi, slchypcl001
slc12vbi,
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the incorrect comparison operator.
If you change `$z -eq $name` to `$z -contains $name`, your script should work as expected.